# Rotating shape moves together with the camera when agent moves

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, 3d, jogl

I created a 3D game where an agent can move in multiple directions (north,south...) .

It works okay ,but when I added another shape - pyramid - to the code , then when I 
move the agent , the pyramid moves with him , meaning it sticks with the movement of the agent (aka camera) .

Any idea how to make the shape static ?

Enabling the line `gl2.glLoadIdentity();` causes the pyramid to stick with the camera . Disabling `gl2.glLoadIdentity();` causes the pyramid not to appear .

**CODE:**

class : **Pyramid.java**

```
import javax.media.opengl.GL2;


public class Pyramid {


    private int m_pyramid;


    public void createPyramid(GL2 gl2) 
    {
        m_pyramid = gl2.glGenLists(1);
        gl2.glNewList(m_pyramid, GL2.GL_COMPILE);

        //  set texture parameters
        gl2.glTexParameteri ( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL2.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        gl2.glTexParameteri( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL2.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

        gl2.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES); // of the pyramid

        // Font-face triangle
        gl2.glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // Red
        gl2.glVertex3d(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Green
        gl2.glVertex3d(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Blue
        gl2.glVertex3d(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        // Right-face triangle
        gl2.glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // Red
        gl2.glVertex3d(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Blue
        gl2.glVertex3d(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Green
        gl2.glVertex3d(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        // Back-face triangle
        gl2.glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // Red
        gl2.glVertex3d(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Green
        gl2.glVertex3d(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Blue
        gl2.glVertex3d(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        // Left-face triangle
        gl2.glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // Red
        gl2.glVertex3d(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Blue
        gl2.glVertex3d(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Green
        gl2.glVertex3d(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        gl2.glEnd(); // of the pyramid
        gl2.glEndList();

    }

}
```

**WorldController.java**

```
class WorldController extends GLCanvas implements GLEventListener, KeyListener 
{
    private Point3D m_agent , m_center , m_coordinate1 , m_coordinate2 , m_coordinate3;
    private GLU m_glu = new GLU();
    private Pyramid m_pyra = new Pyramid();

        public WorldController ()
    {
        this.addGLEventListener(this);

        //  initialize m_agent and axis
        this.m_agent = new Point3D(750,200,1200);
        this.m_coordinate1 = new Point3D(1,0,0);
        this.m_coordinate2 = new Point3D(0,1,0);
        this.m_coordinate3 = new Point3D(0,0,1);
        this.m_center = new Point3D(0,0,0);
    }

        @Override
    public void init (GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) 
    {

        GL2 gl2 = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2(); // get the OpenGL graphics context
        gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);          // get GL Utilities
        gl2.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl2.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl2.glClearDepth(1.0f);
        gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl2.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl2.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);
        gl2.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); // blends colors nicely, and smoothes out lighting


        // bind the pyramid with the current GL2
        this.m_pyra.createPyramid(gl2);

        /**
         * Creating the listener 
         */
        ((Component) gLDrawable).addKeyListener(this);

    }


        @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable)
    {
        final GL2 gl2 = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl2.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl2.glLoadIdentity();

        //  set m_center and look at
        m_center.setPoint(m_agent.getX() - m_coordinate3.getX() , 
                   m_agent.getY() - m_coordinate3.getY() ,
                   m_agent.getZ() - m_coordinate3.getZ());

        m_glu.gluLookAt(m_agent.getX(),m_agent.getY(),m_agent.getZ(),
                      m_center.getX(),m_center.getY(),m_center.getZ(),
                      m_coordinate2.getX(),m_coordinate2.getY(),m_coordinate2.getZ());


        /**
         * pyramid 
         */

        gl2.glPushMatrix();
        // gl2.glLoadIdentity(); 
        gl2.glTranslatef(-2f, 0.0f, -10.0f); // translate left and into the screen
        gl2.glRotatef(anglePyramid, 0.1f, 1.0f, -0.1f); // rotate about the y-axis
        gl2.glCallList(5);
        gl2.glPopMatrix();   // <-- and here?
        anglePyramid += speedPyramid;

    }


    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable,int x,int y,int width,int height) 
    {

        GL2 gl2 = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2(); // get the OpenGL 2 graphics context
        if(height <= 0) height = 1;            // prevent divide by zero

        float aspect = (float)width / (float)height;
        gl2.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        gl2.glLoadIdentity();
        m_glu.gluPerspective(50.0f, aspect, 1.0, 10000.0);
        gl2.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl2.glLoadIdentity();
    }
}
```

Here are some pictures of the agent while moving : 
[image]

[image]

**LIVE VIDEO that might explain the problem** : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCBqx69b_e4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Where, in the code, are you positioning your camera? I only saw the code tha draw pyramid.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to strip off the code that generate the display list from the display function. Put it inside an init function or any function that you use to initialize your objects.

Second, only put inside this generation code, transformation and definitions that are important to construct your object (pyramid). Don't put inside it any transformation that is related to positioning it into the world system. Rememeber, it only need to be generated once and, while your list name is valid, you only need to call it over and over to display it into the framebuffer.

Don't put a glLoadIdentity() inside a display list, they will reset your model view matrix and, I sure, isn't what you want. To preserve the contents of your model view matrix, you can use the matrix stack subsytem, by using glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix function calls.

So, in regard of your code I wold suggest the following modifications:

```
@Override
public void init (GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) 
{

    GL2 gl2 = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2(); // get the OpenGL graphics context
    gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);          // get GL Utilities
    gl2.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl2.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glClearDepth(1.0f);
    gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl2.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LEQUAL);
    gl2.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);
    gl2.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); // blends colors nicely, and smoothes out lighting
    ((Component) gLDrawable).addKeyListener(this);

    // ADDED HERE, OR IN ANY POSITION THAT MAKE MORE SENSE
    int pyramid = gl2.glGenLists(1);
    gl2.glNewList(pyramid, GL2.GL_COMPILE);
    // gl2.glLoadIdentity();  // reset the model-view matrix  <-- TAKE THIS OFF
    gl2.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES); // of the pyramid

    // Font-face triangle
    gl2.glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // Red
    gl2.glVertex3d(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Green
    gl2.glVertex3d(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Blue
    gl2.glVertex3d(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    // Right-face triangle
    gl2.glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // Red
    gl2.glVertex3d(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Blue
    gl2.glVertex3d(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Green
    gl2.glVertex3d(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    // Back-face triangle
    gl2.glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // Red
    gl2.glVertex3d(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Green
    gl2.glVertex3d(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Blue
    gl2.glVertex3d(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    // Left-face triangle
    gl2.glTexCoord3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // Red
    gl2.glVertex3d(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Blue
    gl2.glVertex3d(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Green
    gl2.glVertex3d(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);


    gl2.glEnd(); // of the pyramid
    gl2.glEndList();

    // END HERE
}


@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable)
{
    final GL2 gl2 = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl2.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl2.glLoadIdentity();

    // agent and center settings
    m_center.setPoint(m_agent.getX() - m_coordinate3.getX() , 
               m_agent.getY() - m_coordinate3.getY() ,
               m_agent.getZ() - m_coordinate3.getZ());

    m_glu.gluLookAt(m_agent.getX(),m_agent.getY(),m_agent.getZ(),
                  m_center.getX(),m_center.getY(),m_center.getZ(),
                  m_coordinate2.getX(),m_coordinate2.getY(),m_coordinate2.getZ());


     /**
     * pyramid 
     */

    glPushMatrix();  // <-- did you note this function here?

    gl2.glTranslatef(-2f, 0.0f, -10.0f); // translate left and into the screen
    gl2.glRotatef(anglePyramid, 0.1f, 1.0f, -0.1f); // rotate about the y-axis

    gl2.glCallList(pyramid);
    glPopMatrix();   // <-- and here?
    anglePyramid += speedPyramid;
```

This will not solve your problem completely, once you didn't show how you are controlling the camera. But try to put a glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix as indicated in code

Ps. after looking again into your code, I noted this piece of code:

```
 // agent and center settings
    m_center.setPoint(m_agent.getX() - m_coordinate3.getX() , 
               m_agent.getY() - m_coordinate3.getY() ,
               m_agent.getZ() - m_coordinate3.getZ());

    m_glu.gluLookAt(m_agent.getX(),m_agent.getY(),m_agent.getZ(),
                  m_center.getX(),m_center.getY(),m_center.getZ(),
                  m_coordinate2.getX(),m_coordinate2.getY(),m_coordinate2.getZ());
```

What is the purpose of m_center.setPoint...? What do this function does? I guess your problem could be here.

Comment: After changing the code as you suggested , the pyramid isn't showed to the user . Please see the new code above . If I enable the identity matrix , then it goes back to the initial problem - camera & shape together .

Comment: BTW , the `m_center` and `m_glu.gluLookAt(...)` you mentioned above , are for setting the viewport of the agent , so he well start moving around from the center of the screen and not from some random side of the rectangular room .

Comment: Ok, your problem is with gluLookAt. It is pointing to a space that there is no object. If you wanna test it, I suggest to modified it to `gluLookAt(m_agent.getX(),m_agent.getY(),m_agent.getZ(), -2, 0, -10, m_coordinate2.getX(),m_coordinate2.getY(),m_coordinate2.getZ());`. As you can see, the second coordinates point to the object.

Comment: Please see the pictures above : the first one is with the change you requested , the second one is with the "regular" line . In both cases the pyramid travels with me , only if I allow `gl2.glLoadIdentity();`

Comment: When you enable glLoadIdentity, you are deleting the effects that your glLookAt has set up. If your are not seeing this object, probably is because you are drawing in a point that is outside of your view. From your code, agent is borned at point (500, 100, 1000) and is looking to a point (500, 100, 999), while your pyramid is located at position (-2, 0, -10). You cant see it even. Put your agent at (0, 0, 10) and you will see it.

Comment: I searched for the object everywhere , I can't see it . The actual world is a cube , you can see it (hopefully) from the pictures. The agent allows me to travel anywhere within the cube , and even outside it - so I searched for it but nothing , it's like the pyramid was never created .

Comment: Are you sure that the center of your cube is at (0, 0, 0)? Your code seems to me, correct now. I believe your problem is at gluLookAt set up or at pyramid position. I suggest you to try 2 things: change `glTranslatef(-2f, 0.0f, -10.0f);` to `glTranslatef(500, 100, 1000);` or do incremental additions to your code. First take off `gluLookAt` and `glTranslatef(-2f, 0.0f, -10.0f);`. You must see your pyramid by now. So, start adding each function carefully without loosing its position. Indeed, doing this you will be able to see where are your cube and where your pyramid is borned relative to it.

Comment: Please see a preview of my live code , it refuses to work without the identity matrix : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCBqx69b_e4&feature=youtu.be ... I tried to play with the lines you mentioned but I can't find the Pyramid , so my guess is that it's not created .

Comment: Im sorry to say, but I cant help you anymore without more code. That one that you show here is correct to me. In order to help you further more I need to see you display function and any related data

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're doing improper matrix transformation between world coordinates and camera coordinates.  All glLoadIdentity does is set your initial reference to the identity matrix, which is probably on top of your head if you're not doing the transformation right.

See this:
http://www.matrix44.net/cms/notes/opengl-3d-graphics/coordinate-systems-in-opengl